# Get context path in Java web application

Tags: java

I am trying to get the project context path in Java web application. My project is located in `D:\GED\WSysGED` directory, I want to get that path. In my research, I found two ways to do this: The first uses `System.getProperty` like so:

```
String path= System.getProperty("user.dir");  
System.out.println(path);
```

But that code returns `D:\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse`, where the Eclipse executable file is located.

The second way is using a servlet.

I created that one following this
[tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-the-location-of-my-web-application-context-in-the-file-system.html)

```
public class ContextPathServlet extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        String contextPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<br/>File system context path (in TestServlet): " + contextPath);
    }
}
```

But it is showing `C:\Users\Juan\SysGED\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\wtpwebapps\WSysGED`

What is the correct way to get the project path?

Comment: The second approach is correct. The path returned is your application servers' deployment path. A project path does not exist in Java EE.

Comment: Ok thaks for your answer, just one more thing. path C:\Users\Juan\SysGED.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\wtpwebapps\WSysGED
 is static or the deployment  changes the path sometimes? @home

Comment: It changes, depending on your application server. Please tell us why you need to access that path - other solutions are available?

Comment: I need to crate a folder to store files after a upload, and be avaliable for download, I have a servlet wich shows the files for download but I have hardtyped in the servlet code the path where  files are located . that is the reason why I want to know the path. I dont want to have the path hartyped.@home

Comment: @JuanCamiloMejia check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452484/create-folder-and-upload-file-using-servlet. Seems like it should solve your problem. Ooops just now saw that it is 5 years old post!! will keep the comment in case it helps out someone else :)

Comment: What makes you think the result you got was incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        System.out.println(contextpath);

    }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Please add more information. How did you get to this conclusion? where can we verify that your solution is correct apart from copy pasting your code? why does it work?