# Not able to create directory in init method of httpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

In the below code whenever I am starting the server or entire application the init method is suppose to be called. And the directories intended should be create if they do not exist. But in my system its not being created. And when I am writing a simple java class with main method its creating successfully(directory creation code is in main method itself). For information I am using netbeans 8.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04.

```
public class UserRegistration extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(){
            new File("Directory").mkdirs();
            new File("Directory/Broker").mkdirs();
            new File("Directory/User").mkdirs();
            //these directories are not being created
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

Comment: use full path for directories

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452484/create-folder-and-upload-file-using-servlet