# Add resources folder in .war project under JBDS to store uploaded files

Tags: jakarta-ee, upload, resources, war

i am newbie in javaEE coding, i code under JBoss Developper Studio (JBDS) , so in my .war project i need to store the uploaded files in a folder whichmust be mapped like that for example : localhos:18080/.../images/..
So i have an upload mechanism that is working well to store files in my hard disk,
need just to help to add folder in my project and to redirect the upload to this new folder,

[here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIcWt.jpg)

some need please.

Comment: You don't need to add a folder to your project for that. The servlet that processes the upload can create the folder, on the fly, if it does not exist and it doesn't need to be bind to your project. It can be anywhere on your server. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23453089/1346996).

Comment: thanks for your fast reply , but in my case i am working w REST API and angularJS client , i am not working with  servlet !