# How to get the project base path in Spring mvc web application?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I have spring mvc web application which is deployed on a tomcat server. On that project, I want to create folders and files in the runtime. currently I can create folders in the server root by using `System.getProperty("catalina.base")`. But when I deployed the project in a externel server I cant create folders on the root level of the tomcat server beacuse I don't have permissions. Intead of that I decided to create folders in following directory.

```
tomcat_dirctory/webapps/myproject_directory
```

so I need to create folders and files in side the `myproject_directory` in the runtime. Can anyone tell me what is the path for that. May be I can hardocde that as follows.

```
 System.getProperty("catalina.base") + File.separator + "webapps"+File.separator+"myproject_directory"
```

But Instead of hard coding I prefer to know is there any alternative way to obtain  my project path.

Comment: You can use getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452484/create-folder-and-upload-file-using-servlet

Comment: yes its works fine if I define it inside a GET or POST method. But Supppose I want to define a field in a controller which is going to hold this path value as a string. Then I can use your method.

Comment: check the path exists. If not create directories using mkdirs function.

Comment: String path = servletContext.getRealPath(directories);
     File file = new File(path);
     if (!file.exists()) {
      file.mkdirs();
     }
Refer

Comment: @sumesh Anyway your method was helpful to me. I used getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); inside a InitBinder method . then I can used it anywhere in the controller.

Comment: Ok ! @Nwn ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path.
For example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return the absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of the form http://://index.html would be mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this ServletContext.

The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators.

Resources inside the /META-INF/resources directories of JAR files bundled in the application's /WEB-INF/lib directory must be considered only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR file, in which case the path to the unpacked location must be returned.

This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to translate the given virtual path to a real path.